# Dynamically Update JQueryTools ToolTip with content from an AJAX Call

Tags: asp.net-ajax, jquery-tools, jquery-tooltip

I have looked at the similar issues and none seem to encompass what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically, I just want to get the tool tip text using an ajax call when someone hovers over a link.  I have all of the pieces hooked up, but, calling the ajax call from the onBeforeShow event returns the tooltip before the ajax call can complete.  I tried changing the preDelay option, and that does cause a delay before loading, but doesn't fire the onBeforeShow event until after the delay (therefore having the same effect).  I basically just need the tooltip to wait to show until the ajax call has finished.

I modified it to stick the ajax value in a class var. So, you'll see that it updates with the returned value from the previous call in calls after the first.

Here is a trimmed down version of the code (should run):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication11.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Services" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetDescription(string inputId)
    {
        List<string> status = new List<string>();
        //going to do more here to get real data
        status.Add("New Updated Content");
        return status;
    }

</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #tooltipmedium
        {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: gray;
            height: 310px;
            padding: 40px 30px 10px 60px;
            margin-top: -40px;
            margin-left: -80px;
            width: 616px;
            font-size: 11px;
            color: #fff;
            z-index: 99999 !important;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js "></script>
     <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var description;
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("a[id*=linkButton]").tooltip({
                offset: [330, 40],
                position: "center right",
                predelay: 500,
                onBeforeShow: tooltipBeforeShow

            });


            function tooltipBeforeShow() {
                getDescription();

                this.getTip().html(description);
            }
            function getDescription() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetDescription",
                    data: "{inputId:'111'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        description = data.d[0];

                    }


                });

            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton" runat="server" Text='Hover Over This' Style="text-decoration: none;
            color: #000000;"></asp:LinkButton>
        <div id="tooltipmedium">
            Blah.. Old Text
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the .mouseover() event for the element to call your ajax and then wiring up the .tooltip() in the success function? You'll have to call .tooltip().show() since mouse will already be over the element which would normally cause the tooltip to display.